# Use token from Outlook web add-in for EWS write operations

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to use any tokens from an Outlook add-in for use with authenticating EWS Managed API operations that create or update items?

Apparently the token returned from `mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync` can only be used in read operations. I can indeed verify that is a problem because attempts to send emails or call `UserConfiguration.Update` result in an error:

> The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application.

I have been testing these methods from an ASP.NET Web API App Service in Azure, called from JavaScript in the Outlook add-in.

Apparently `mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync` can be used to *validate* a user, but it is not clear if that can be used in conjunction with `OAuthCredentials` for `ExchangeService.Credentials`.

Are there any options here?  I cannot ask the user for their username and password to authenticate with Exchange.  I am certainly willing to use Graph or the Mail API, but AFAIK there are no ways to update user configuration items with those APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`makeEwsRequestAsync()`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.4/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.4#makeewsrequestasyncdata-callback-usercontext). Both `CreateItem` and `UpdateItem` operations are supported `makeEwsRequestAsync`.

You can find the full list of supported EWS operations in the documentation under [EWS operations that add-ins support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services#ews-operations-that-add-ins-support).

There is also support for calling into [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api) via the add-in but as you noted, Microsoft Graph supports a very limited number mailbox configuration options.

Comment: Thanks Marc, but makeEwsRequestAsync will not work when using UpdateItem on FAI items - it throws an error: "Office extension is not allowed to update this type of item". That's why I'm trying the EWS Managed API, and thus the current problem with only read operations supported with the add-in's token. Perhaps OAuth will work? It's one extra auth step (hopefully once only) but I can live with that